# Remove elements from list with differing number of rows in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list with differing numbers of rows. I want to remove all except for the size I want:
Example:

```
List of 400
$ 1 : num [1:101] 1 5 7 10 11...
$ 2 : num [1:101] 6 2 5 11 15...
$ 3 : num [1:75] 15 12 100 15 5...
$ ...
```

I want to keep everything with [1:101] and discard everything else.

I know this is probably quite simple but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `l[sapply(l,length)==101]`

Comment: or the (almost exact equivalent) `Filter(function(x) length(x) ==5,l)`

Comment: @mnel Interesting, I've never used `Filter`. Did you mean to use `==5` there, or should that read `==101` in this case?

Comment: My typo. `101` in your case.